# stars plot formatting: keys on the graphs

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to create six `stars`-plots with radii named according to the columns of the input data.frame `u`. In other words, I'd like to do without the key legend, and have the key names directly on the stars-plots themselves. Is there a way to do this without looping through the `stars`-plots using `par(mfrow)` ? Thanks.

```
 u = matrix(runif(60),6,10)
 colnames(u) <- as.character(1:10)
 stars( u , locations = NULL , key.loc = c(0,0) , labels=1:6,
   key.labels = colnames(u) , col.lines=1:10, lwd=2 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of fiddling you can get to something workable.

```
sloc <- stars(u,len=0.6,lwd=2, col.lines=1:10)

Map(
  function(x,y) stars(
                  matrix(1,ncol=10,nrow=6),key.loc=c(x,y),
                  key.labels=colnames(u),add=TRUE, lty=3, cex=0.7, len=0.6
                ),
  sloc$Var1, sloc$Var2
)
```

Result:

[image]

You could remove the lines for each segment entirely by specifying `lty=0`, but this leaves the numbers floating out in space awkwardly.